# What is considered on-topic for Salesforce Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to SFSE but I have been active on SO for some years now. I am following the guidelines that I am used to, but I'd like to know what are some of the main differences between us and SO in terms of what we consider to be a quality answer, quality question, etc.

I feel like our userbase is quite different, in that we're a community around development on the Salesforce platform, but does that have to be limited to programming questions? What about questions where people would like to know the best approach to a particular problem which would be considered opinion-based on SO? I've seen some questions like this be flagged here before.

Has broadening the definition of on-topic been considered for this community? [The help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) literally says ask anything Salesforce here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't speak much to the SO comparison but I can talk to the standards as I understand them.

A good, on topic **question** will be specific about what is being asked, and whenever possible it should contain steps for Minimum Viable Reproduction. If the community cannot reproduce the issue, it is difficult to provide good answers.

A good **answer** will be rooted in fact and contain references to back up any claims. In general any linked reference should be quoted (and abridged to the relevant information if necessary). Sometimes if someone needs to build breadth of knowledge to understand the issue I will just provide a "Related Reading" section with a few helpful links, but the general rule is consistent.

Whether or not we will close a question as being `Primarily Opinion Based` is a bit of a crap shoot. Sometimes a question is rooted in opinion but the answer is too important to just close the question even if that close reason does exist. It sure helps to have a question where those opinions can be backed up by facts and experience.

---

Back to your question, if you are using "literally" in the ... literal sense, then I believe you have misinterpreted the help article you linked. The "Ask anything here!" bit refers to the linked Salesforce Success Community as "here". I'll quote it here again:

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Salesforce Stack Exchange is for Salesforce administrators, implementation experts, developers and anybody in-between working on, or with Salesforce products such as the Analytics Cloud or Marketing Cloud(ExactTarget).
>
> The best questions are [those that have specific answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/); Salesforce StackExchange is not a general discussion forum. If you are looking for discussion, ideas or opinions, there are several alternative forums specifically focused on Salesforce:
>
> - [Salesforce Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/) is exactly as its name suggests - a community focused on success with Salesforce. Ask anything here!
> - [Force.com Discussion Boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/) are for more discursive developer-focused questions.
> - [Salesforce IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) is the 'suggestion box' for the Salesforce Technology & Products team - see your idea implemented in a future release!

If you take that first bullet in context, the help article basically states that even if questions are off topic here, they almost certainly will not be in that community.

Comment: Why did I totally read that blurb wrong? Ok makes total sense. Thanks!